# Is it the best to post an answer to my own question and accept it?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

Recently I posted two answers to my own questions

[An integral of rational function with third power of cosine hyperbolic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2150148/an-integral-of-rational-function-with-third-power-of-cosine-hyperbolic-function)

[A closed form for a triple integral with sines and cosines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128300/a-closed-form-for-a-triple-integral-with-sines-and-cosines)

Actually I was a little bit confused whether to edit my question to include the answer or to post it as a separate answer? Also should I accept my answer in that case ?

Comment: What mixedmath said. If you figure out the answer after posting the question, either under your own steam or possibly in response to the comments and/or answers from others, then I consider it a success. Props for asking! Feel free to proceed! A caveat I want to state for the record is that if you knew the answer in advance, and want to show off later, then you should be prepared for a mixed response. Many regulars don't want the askers to "test" them with challenges. If you have found a very sleek way of solving a problem, posting the question is still ok, but the bar is then relatively high.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, actually I thought twice before posting the answer because many will think that I knew the answer in advance and I am trying to show off. This is why I have doubts about my approach and whether I should do the same in the future!

Comment: Zaid, usually we can tell if that is the case :-)

Comment: If you found it later, just say "I found it [thanks to] ..." in your answer and nobody will doubt you unless you have a clear history of showing off.

Comment: The legend is told of Fermat's correspondence with Pascal.  Fermat would pose a problem, spend a month solving the problem, then write Pascal asking if he knew the solution, then send his own solution a week later (so as to demonstrate his quick insight).  Perhaps the oldest known example of repfarming?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, if Fermat was  accused of that, I will not be surprised If you felt the same towards me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Question part is for questions, and the Answers part is for answers. So if you have an answer to your question, add your own answer. If you think it is a complete answer (and the best answer given), then you can accept it.

Comment: It might be worth adding that [self-answers are explicitly encouraged](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Yes they are.  And I know this is not an instructibles site but sometimes I have found something so cool that I want to share it.  But I definitely hold off a few days before accepting my own answer because this is a large community with hundreds of man-years of experience and someone might pop up with a surprise that takes me in another direction.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes yes, but just today I accepted another user's answers to one of my questions that I had answered.  "Give credit where credit is due" and all that.

The other user was a lot more experienced than me and came up with a very clever answer that went way beyond what I had imagined.  So he deserved the credit.

Now I will have to order some parts to build the thing, but I have full confidence that it will work.

Ya just gotta love StackExchange for things like that.